# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **8 August 2022** to bring in 1 more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on 8 August, users can [nominate themselves](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On 15 August, if there are 2 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 2 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on 23 August (or 30 August, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.